# Missing Schemas in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench, database-schema

I am having an issue in MySQL Workbench, where many of my created schemas are missing. I was in a Coding Bootcamp, and all the schemas that I created during that period vanished. The ones created beforehand are all still there. I'm pretty sure I am using the same user account and I checked the privileges. I also checked usr/local/var/mysql and the missing schemas are not located in this folder. So my question is what happened to them? I certainly did not delete them. Maybe someone else did when I wasn't looking? Or could this have been caused by an update? I went several months without opening Workbench, so I'm not exactly sure when this happened. I have searched for hours and hours on SO and google and have not found an answer. Any ideas are much appreciated!
Also, I am on MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 if that helps.

Comment: you can take a look into the data directory ad see which folders are there

Comment: You are correct, they are all there. But for some reason, my admin name does not show up under Sharing & Permissions, so I don't have access. I will look into this further. Thank you.